# Firebase cloud function not triggering when deleting in transaction

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

in my Android app I'm deleting some data from my Firebase Database tree, in a transaction because I want to delete multiple paths from the tree at the same time. The path that is deleted in a transaction is the following:

pseudocode:

```
begin transaction
for all eventId's in a list delete member with memberid
/contexts/uid/contextId/events/eventId/members/memberId
end for

then delete member from
/contexts/uid/contextId/members/memberId
commit

end transaction
```

I use the following java code in my android app and it works very well

```
 database.getReference(Global.DEV_PREFIX).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                for (String eventKey : eventKeySet) {
                    mutableData.child("/contexts/" + getCurrentUserId() + "/" + contextId + "/events/" + eventKey + "/members/" + member.getId()).setValue(null);
                }

                mutableData.child("/contexts/" + getCurrentUserId() + "/" + contextId + "/members/" + member.getId()).setValue(null);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (databaseError == null) {
                    callback.onSucess();
                } else {
                    callback.onError(databaseError);
                }
            }
        });
```

But now I want to have a cloud function that listens on the deletion of the member and deletes some files from the storage.

I did a lot of tests and I can not understand the behaviour. The cloud functions are triggered when deleting the member in a non transactional way. But when deleting in a transaction, the .onDelete event is never triggered in the server (nor the onWrite event). My Cloud function is defined in the following way:

```
exports.memberDeleteTrigerTest = functions.database.ref('/contexts/{userId}/{contextId}/members/{memberId}/')
    .onDelete(event => {

console.log('Hello memberDeleteTrigerTest');

return ;
});
```

I tried to listen to a inner property of the member without success:

```
exports.memberDeleteTrigerTest = functions.database.ref('/contexts/{userId}/{contextId}/members/{memberId}/id')
    .onDelete(event => {

console.log('Hello memberDeleteTrigerTest');

return ;
});
```

Maybe the way I delete the data in the transaction in the Android app is not the appropriate. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So I don't know if is this the problem `mutableData.child("/contexts/" + getCurrentUserId() + "/" + contextId + "/members/" + member.getId()).setValue(null);` . So here is my suggestion, change code to this `mutableData.child("/contexts/" + getCurrentUserId() + "/" + contextId + "/members/" + member.getId()).removeValue();`, what i'm thinking is because you in java is setValue(null) and in function you have onDelete the cloud function not fires.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the method removeValue() is not available for mutableData.child(...).

In addition, not only the onDelete event is not triggering. The onWrite event is not triggering to, but this event has to be triggered when setting a new value (or null value).

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this in my own function.  My function gets invoked with deletes occurring both inside a transaction and not.  Can you simplify the example down to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem?